# Incorrect act OpenCl/C++ script on CPU and GPU

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, cpu

I have transfered OpenCl/C++ script to new machine (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz, NVIDIA TESLA C2070).

I ran it successfully on GPU and I got correct results (Here when I tried run it on CPU it gave me incorrect results 0), then I wanted to run it on CPU so I installed Intel driver (http://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo).

When I compiled it I faced this problem:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!
```

I worked around it by putting   -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm -lpthread as parameters to g++.

The problem now is it gives me correct results when I put CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU and wrong results (0 looks like it does not work) when I put CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU.

Expected Output:

```
315360000   0.345   0.349   0.345   9
```

Wrong Output:

```
315360000   0   0   0   9
```

Any idea!!

Comment: Please show some example code that reproduces the problem (i.e. a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: thanks @jprice, In fact I did not put the code because it was working on GPU (in the same machine) before I installed intel driver to run it on CPU also.

Comment: It sounds like there is some kind of race condition or undefined behavior that is causing it to sometimes fail the assertion. Posting the code or a minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: @sabreitweiser , jprice , I added the code.

Comment: @RamiAqqad Great! I'll do my best to answer tomorrow if no one else has answered by then.

Comment: You should be calling `checkError()` after *every single* OpenCL API call, not just the program build. The program could be failing at any point, and you will never find out about it unless you actually check these error codes.

Comment: thx @jprice but it is working on my laptop (the other machine) and it is also working correctly on same machine when put  CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU!!.

Besides of that, before I installed the intel driver it was working on GPU ( CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU).
After all that, Do you think the problem is in Code!!

Comment: It doesn't matter that it works on other devices. You might only be getting API errors on the one platform that it doesn't work on. You should *always* check *every* OpenCL error code, with *absolutely no exceptions*.

Comment: @jprice Yes I did.
------------------------------ 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_331_uvm': Invalid argument
Error during operation 'clGetDeviceIDs': -1
----------------

Comment: @RamiAqqad Could you edit the question to be more specific about the output you expect and the (incorrect) output you're getting? I think I found an indexing error, which would give either 0's or garbage numbers.

Comment: If you're getting a `modprobe` error, that indicates an issue with your driver installation, not with your code.

Comment: @jprice , yes I expected that, but what should I do?

Comment: I fixed it and now:
`    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
checkError(ret, "clGetPlatformIDs");
cout << ret;
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
cout << ret;
checkError(ret, "clGetDeviceIDs");`

The output was:
Error during operation 'clGetDeviceIDs': -1
0
-1

Comment: I am not be able to deal with this problem although I found these links :
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)
I made some modifications depending on the code in this link https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/498968/printing-all-opencl-devices-not-detecting-all-opencl-devices-under-windows/

```
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(2, platforms, &ret_num_platforms);
cout << ret;
    //ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);  // Execute me on CPU
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[1], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices); // Execute me on GPU
```